# Jupyter keyboard shortcut for running a specific cell

Tags: python, keyboard-shortcuts, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

In my workflow with Jupyter notebook, I have a cell like:

```
%run myscript.py
```

Which loads the latest version of a script with functions I'm using. I am constantly updating this script and using its function in my notebook. Therefore, I find myself constantly going back to the first cell and running it. It would be very convenient if there was a keyboard shortcut to do that (e.g. run the first cell). Does it exist?

Comment: I want to run the current cell without creating a new one. I don't want my cursor to automatically go to the next cell by itself. Is there a shortcut for that?

Answer (score 2):

You can click "Ctrl + Enter" to run only the chosen cell no matter it is "edit mode" or "command mode".

If you want to know more available commands, just input `Esc` to change you current mode to "command mode" and input "h" to show the Keyboard shortcuts modal.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand how this answers my question. I want a keyboard shortcut to run the first cell even if I'm not in it.

Comment: @RS Sorry, I'm afraid not.

Comment: I want to run the current cell without creating a new one. I don't want my cursor to automatically go to the next cell by itself. Is there a shortcut for that?

Comment: @CharlieParker Use `Ctrl+Enter` you won't leave your current cell, meanwhile `Shift+Enter` do.

Answer (score 2):

**An important update**
If you install nbextensions then there is a nice widget for that called

"**Initialization cells**"

Here is the link to nbextensions
https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html

The following comments are my old comments and can be neglected.

You can do it by running the following code:

```
%%javascript
Jupyter.notebook.execute_cells([0])
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47572981/7538689

Note: the cell number in this command is different from the cell number that appears on the left side of the cell in Jupyter. For this command, the cell number is based on the order of the cell in the Jupyter Notebook, from top to bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Press `Ctrl + Enter` to run only the cell without move to the next one.

By the way `alt + Enter` does this second behavior (creat new one).

Comment: I want to run the current cell without creating a new one. I don't want my cursor to automatically go to the next cell by itself. Is there a shortcut for that?