# execute a Jupyter Notebook cell programmatically

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

Is it possible for a Jupyter Notebook cell to execute another cell programmatically? (i.e. using Python)

And if so, is it possible to specify the cell number to execute?

Answer (score 41):

There is a javascript function called `execute_cells` ([see it on Github](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/blob/881268f64245e0829173d1a6dc7aad7db39795d3/notebook/static/notebook/js/notebook.js#L2407)) that when given an list of cell indices runs those cells.

```
%%javascript
Jupyter.notebook.execute_cells([0]) # 0 to run first cell in notebook etc.
```

If you need to run it specifically in a Python code cell, one can use the `Javascript` function in the `IPython.display` module to execute javascript

```
from IPython.display import Javascript
Javascript("Jupyter.notebook.execute_cells([2])")
```

Note that this will move the cursor to executed cells.  If you wish to get back to the cursor position, you may get the number of the next cell in order to execute it (code adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39639111/812102)) :

```
%%javascript
Jupyter.notebook.execute_cells([0]) # 0 to run first cell in notebook etc.

var output_area = this;
// find my cell element
var cell_element = output_area.element.parents('.cell');
// which cell is it?
var cell_idx = Jupyter.notebook.get_cell_elements().index(cell_element);
Jupyter.notebook.execute_cells([cell_idx+1]) # execute next cell
```

Comment: I get a python error: **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Jupyter'**
What module do I import to access 'Jupyter' ?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to specify that this is from the notebook's javascript, so you need to use the `%%javascript` cell magic command to run the cell as javascript. I updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: As specified in the question Python is needed to call the execution of the cell.
Can Python be used to execute this Javascript function?

Comment: Why do you need to run it in a python code cell specifically? Either way, I've added how to run it in a python code cell. If you really don't want to use javascript, I don't think there's a simple solution - perhaps you could use nbconvert?

Comment: Is there any way to find the ```cell_idx ``` of any cell?

Comment: Apparently this won't work with jupyterlab. :( https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/5660#issuecomment-514728559

Comment: Big thanks, it works like charm! :)

Comment: does not work in vscode. Any ideas how to do this in vscode

Answer (score 4):

I would like to add to the answer @Louise Davies. If you want to execute a range of cells, use:

```
from IPython.display import Javascript
Javascript("Jupyter.notebook.execute_cell_range(10,20)")
```

Comment: Is it possible to execute another cell after current executing cell? (in case current running cell takes a while)? Javascript("Jupyter.notebook.execute_cell_range(10,20)")  // takes a while
  Javascript("Jupyter.notebook.execute_cell_range(2,4)") // run another cell