# How to run specific range of cells in Jupyter Notebook using keyboard shortcut?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm aware of:

- `run all cells below`
- `run all cells above`
- `run all cells`
- running a specific cell using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

I've added custom shortcuts for the first two items (run all below and run all above). But I have to move the cursor to a specific cell, say, 20th, and then do `run all cells below`.

Is there a way I can have a shortcut that runs arbitrary range of cells, say 20th to 30th?

Comment: this might help create a script https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47567834/execute-a-jupyter-notebook-cell-programmatically